# add image from ObservableList to tableview

Tags: image, tableview, observablelist

I have a String variable "image" in an Animal class.

I then add this to an ObservableList which is then added to TableView.

My code below is Displaying the location of the image but I want it to display the actual image

What is the best way to do this. Thanks!

```
TableColumn<Animal, String> imgCol = new TableColumn<>("IMAGE");
imgCol.setPrefWidth(200);
imgCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("_image"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Managed to get it working.

imgCol.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Animal, String>() {
                ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
                @Override
                public void updateItem(String valid, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(valid, empty);
                    if (valid != null) {
                        imageview.setImage(new Image(valid));
                        imageview.setFitWidth(90);
                        imageview.setFitHeight(90);
                        imageview.setPreserveRatio(true);
                        imageview.setSmooth(true);
                        setGraphic(imageview);
                    }else{

                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            });
```